# Scrapy, HTTP status code 200 and redirections

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to follow redirections using scrapy, however i'm having the following issue:

if i don't set an user-agent for the t.co url shortener, i get 301 status code and this response body:

```
# 'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
<noscript>
    <META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://sn.im/29m4uw5">
</noscript>
<title>http://sn.im/29m4uw5</title>
<script>
    window.opener = null; location.replace("http:\/\/sn.im\/29m4uw5")
</script>
```

now, when i set an user agent (PS 3), i get 200 status code and same response body (and redirection isn't solved). I need to set an user-agent to track chain redirections, like if i visit them.

So, i need solve redirections although the HTTP status code don't be 3XX (like in this case, 200).

Thank you for your help!

PS: the url used for testing is http://t.co/b00VzIsr6l

PS 2: would i need something like scrapyjs?

PS 3: scrapy project settings are:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': 400,
'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware': 550,
'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.redirect.RedirectMiddleware': 600}

REDIRECT_ENABLED = True
METAREFRESH_ENABLED = True

USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
```